# Unable to access values from json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

So I was working on two independent projects for data analysis in Python 3:
1.
To analyse the given json data and print the s['number'], s['people'] and s['craft']

```
import urllib.request
import sklearn
with urllib.request.urlopen("http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json") as url:
  s = url.read()
print("Dataset:",s)
print("Tot no. of people in space:",s['number'])
peeps=s['people']
craft=s['craft']
for i in peeps:
   print(i)
for j in craft:
   print(j)
```

2. 

To analyse the given json data and print the latitude and longitude of the ISS

```
import urllib.request
import sklearn
with urllib.request.urlopen("http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json") as url:
    s = url.read()
print("Dataset:",s)
loc=s['iss_position']
lat=float(loc['latitude'])
long=float(loc['longitude'])
print(lat,long)
```

However, these codes failed to give me the desired results. Did I make a mistake? Or did I forget something?

Comment: *However, these codes failed to give me the desired results* Add the output you are getting and also add what output you expect to have.

Comment: Please post the errors instead of mentioning it "failed". Also, the variable `s` is out of context

Comment: You're never using `sklearn` here, so why does the question title say "ML"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s` is a string, not a dataframe.

Strings cannot be indexed by words, only numbers.

Dictionaries can indexed by keys, and you can use `s = json.loads(url.read())` to get one, assuming the URL returns a JSON object